# Center and dynamically size the horizontal drop down menu bar using CSS

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

What I am trying to do is limit the horizontal size of the menu to whatever number and size of the options there are.  And also center the whole thing.  Right now everything is at the top and left justified.  In addition it also takes up the entire width of the page.

I would like it to appear after a header image and be centered with a dynamic size appropriate for the number of selections.

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">
        <meta name="viewport" content="Width=device-Width, initial-scale=1">
        <style>
            /* CSSTerm.com Horizontal Easy DropDown CSS menu */

            .drop_menu {
                position:relative;
                background:#005555;
                padding:0;
                margin:auto;
                list-style-type:none;
                height:40px;
                width:360;
            }
            .drop_menu li {
            float:left;
            display:inline-block;
            }
            .drop_menu li a {
                padding:12px 20px;
                display:block;
                color:#fff;
                text-decoration:none;
                font:12px arial, verdana, sans-serif;
                border-right:1px solid #75809a;
            }

            /* Submenu */
            .drop_menu ul {
                text-align: center;
                position:absolute;
                left:-9999px;
                top:-9999px;
                list-style-type:none;
                display:inline;
            }
            .drop_menu li:hover { position:relative; background:#75809a;  }
            .drop_menu li:hover ul {
                left:0px;
                top:38px;
                background:#75809a;
                padding:0px;
            }

            .drop_menu li:hover ul li a {
                padding:10px;
                display:block;
                width:168px;
                text-indent:15px;
                background-color:#75809a;
            }
            .drop_menu li:hover ul li a:hover { background:#005555;  }

        </style>
        <title>Home menu for YavapaiNA.org site</title>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/Version_1_0_1.js"></script>
        <SCRIPT TYPE="text/javascript">
            //      var ScreenWidth = document.documentElement.clientWidth;
            //      var ScreenHeight = document.documentElement.clientHeight;

            var LeftsideMeetingsPopup = ((document.documentElement.clientWidth / 2) - 550);
            var TopOfMeetingsPopup = ((document.documentElement.clientHeight / 2) - 300);

            var LeftsideEventsPopup = ((document.documentElement.clientWidth / 2) - 300);
            var TopOfEventsPopup = ((document.documentElement.clientHeight / 2) - 230);

            var MeetingsParams = 'Width=1100,Height=600,Left=' + LeftsideMeetingsPopup + ',Top=' + TopOfMeetingsPopup + ',scrollbars=no';
            var EventsParams = 'Width=600,Height=460,Left=' + LeftsideEventsPopup + ',Top=' + TopOfEventsPopup + ',scrollbars=no';


            function Meetings_Popup(mylink, windowname) {
             if (!window.focus) return true;
             var href;
             if (typeof(mylink) == 'string') href = mylink;
             else href = mylink.href;
             window.open(href, windowname, MeetingsParams);
             return false;
            }

            function Events_Popup(mylink, windowname) {
             if (!window.focus) return true;
             var href;
             if (typeof(mylink) == 'string') href = mylink;
             else href = mylink.href;
             window.open(href, windowname, EventsParams);
             return false;
            }
            //          alert(MeetingsParams);
            //          alert(EventsParams);

        </SCRIPT>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div align="center" style="width:360">
            <ul class="drop_menu">
                <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                <li><A HREF="/Meetings_Popup.html" onClick="return Meetings_Popup(this, 'notes')">Meeting List</a></li>
                <li><A HREF="/Events_Popup.html" onClick="return Events_Popup(this, 'notes')">Events</a></li>
                <li>
                    <a href='#'>Misc Links</a>
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="#">Arizona</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Camp Verde</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Some Services</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: So you want the whole top bar centered and what else? it is a little vague to me :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let me know if this helps

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.drop_menu {
  background: #005555;
  list-style-type: none;
  height: 40px;
  width: 460px;
  display: flex;
  padding: 0;
  margin:0 auto;
}
img {
  float: left;
}
.drop_menu li a {
  padding: 12px 20px;
  display: inline-block;
  color: #fff;
  text-decoration: none;
  font: 12px arial, verdana, sans-serif;
}
.drop_menu > li {
  border-right: 1px solid #75809a;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}
.drop_menu > li:last-child {
  border-right: none;
}


/* Submenu */

.drop_menu ul {
  text-align: left;
  position: absolute;
  left: -9999px;
  top: -9999px;
  list-style-type: none;
  display: inline;
}

.drop_menu li:hover {
  position: relative;
  background: #75809a;
}

.drop_menu li:hover ul {
  left: 0px;
  top: 38px;
  background: #75809a;
  padding: 0px;
}

.drop_menu li:hover ul li a {
  padding: 10px;
  display: block;
  width: 168px;
  text-indent: 15px;
  background-color: #75809a;
}

.drop_menu li:hover ul li a:hover {
  background: #005555;
}
```

```html
<div style="width:100%; background-color: red; height: 100px;">
  <img src="http://placehold.it/100x40" />
  <ul class="drop_menu">
    <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="/Meetings_Popup.html" onClick="return Meetings_Popup(this, 'notes')">Meeting List</a></li>
    <li><a href="/Events_Popup.html" onClick="return Events_Popup(this, 'notes')">Events</a></li>
    <li>
      <a href='#'>Misc Links</a>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Arizona</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Camp Verde</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Some Services</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```